# What is the safe NEAR blockchain validation node restart procedure?

Tags: nearprotocol

Will I lose my validation status if I promptly restart the node with the new config (e.g. telemetry endpoint changes).

Should I just restake after the restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If you restart immediately you shouldn't lose your validator status. However, if you take down your node for a while your node might be kicked out.